# Sum of $f(i)$ that contain element $i$ in defined sets?

Tags: combinatorics

Let $S = \{1, 2, 3,........, m\}, m >3$. Let $X_1,.........,X_n$ be subsets of $S$ each of size $3$. Define a function $f$ from $S$ to the set of natural numbers as, $f(i)$ is the number of sets $X_j$ that contain the element $i$. That is $f(i)=\left | \left\{j \mid i\in X_j \right\} \right|$   then $ \sum_{i=1}^{m} f(i)$ is $:$

1. $3m$
2. $3n$
3. $2m+1$
4. $2n+1$

---

My attempt :

Take $m=5$ , so $S = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$

Number of subsets of os $S$ each of size $3$ ,i.e., $n= ^5C_3 = 10$. These are following :

$\{1,2,3\}$,  $\{1,2,4\}$ , $\{1,2,5\}$ ,$\{2,3,4\}$ , $\{2,3,5\}$

$\{3,4,5\}$  , $\{3,4,1\}$, $\{4,5,1\}$ , $\{4,5,2\}$, $\{5,1,3\}$

Now, number of sets that contain element $1 = f(1) = 6$

number of sets that contain element $2 = f(2) = 6$

number of sets that contain element $3 = f(3) = 6$

number of sets that contain element $4 = f(4) = 6$

number of sets that contain element $5 = f(5) = 6$

hence, sum of $f(i) =  \sum_{i=1}^{m} f(i) = f(1) + f(2) + f(3) + f(4) + f(5)=6+6+6+6+6 = 30$

so, options

1. $3*5=15$
2. $3*10=30$
3. $2*5+1=11$
4. $2*10+1=21$

---

> Can you explain in formal way please?

Comment: The family of subsets $X_j$, is a partition of $S$, they are all possible subsets of cardinality 3 or they are a different thing? The question isnt clear.

Comment: It's comptitive exam GATE's question http://gateoverflow.in/988/gate2006_25

Comment: @Masacroso The question looks quite clear to me. Nothing there says that the $X_j$"s are disjoint or that their union is $S$ or that they are all of the $3$-element subsets of $S$. It just says that they are $3$-element subsets of $S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the set $P$ of all pairs $(i,j)$ such that $i\in X_j$.  The definition of $f$ says that each $i\in S$ is the first component of $f(i)$ pairs in $P$.  So the total number of pairs in $P$ is $\sum_{i=1}^mf(i)$.  On the other hand, each $j\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ is the second component of exactly three pairs in $P$ because $X_j$ has exactly three elements.  So the total number of pairs in $P$ is $n\cdot 3$. Since both ways of computing the number of pairs in $P$ must give the same result, $\sum_{i=1}^mf(i)=3n$.

Answer (score 1):

Let we extent your problem like this.

"$S=\{1,2,3,...m\}, m>3, $ Let $X_1,X_2.. $ each of size $k<m$, $\ldots$"

The answer is "$f(i)=m.C(m-1,k-1)$". In particular, in your attemt, $k=3, m=5$ and so $f(i)=m.C(m-1,k-1)=5.C(4,2)=5.6=30$".

The reason is that .

Let $S$ is a set with cardinality m. The number of $S$'s subsets that includes a constant element, with cardinality k is $C(m-1,k-1)$". For this; choose a constant element from $S$ and so new $S$ 's (say $S_1$) cardinality $m-1$, and then   $C(m-1,k-1)$ says you that the number of subsets $S_1$ with cardinality $k-1$. Also the subsets have not the constant element so you add them and obtain you want. You have $m$ constant elements and then "$f(i)=m.C(m-1,k-1)$"

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.